# Subring $R \subset \Bbb{Q}[X]$. Evaluation hom. $R/(f) \to \Bbb{Z}/(f(a))$ gives me a weird result (not true), but everything looks correct.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, minimal-polynomials, ring-isomorphism

Let $R = \text{Int}[X] \subset \Bbb{Q}[X]$ be the subring of integer-valued polynomials.

Fix an $a \in \Bbb{Z}$.

Let $f \in R$ be one such irreducible, monic polynomial.  Then $\psi: R/(f) \to \Bbb{Z}/(f(a)), \ \psi(g + (f)) = g(a) + (f(a))$ is a surjective ring homomorphism.  If $g(X) = h(X) \pmod f$ then $f(X) \mid g(X) - h(X) \implies f(a) \mid g(a) - h(a)$.

$\psi(h + g) = h(a) + g(a) + (f(a)) = \psi(h) + \psi(g)$.  Similarly $\psi(hg) = \psi(h)\psi(g)$.

$\psi$ is surjective since we can achieve any $z \in \Bbb{Z}$ by evaluating integer polynomials $X + d$ over all $d \in \Bbb{Z}$ which are in $R$.

---

But $f \in R \subset \Bbb{Q}[X]$ so if $f$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{Q}[X]$ then it is also irreducible in $R$, so that $(f)$ (in $R$) is also maximal in $R$ and $R/(f)$ is a field.

Then $\psi$ is actually an isomorphism since it's kernel has to be $(0)$.  Thus $R/(f) \simeq \Bbb{Z}/(f(a))$ for any $a \in \Bbb{Z}$, so you get weird isomorphisms for all the different moduli $f(a)$.

Therefore, something in my understanding is not correct.  Can you help me suss this out?

Comment: Does “integer valued polynomials” mean polynomials with rational coefficients that define functions $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin precisely ^_^

Comment: I'm looking at Shinzel's hypothesis, and that is the math I came up with hence the integer-valued polys.

Comment: $\phi$ need not be an isomorphism if $f$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$. It could be the zero map. E.g., this happens if $f(x) = x+a-1$, since $f(a)=1$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin do you mean $\psi$?  Also, which part of my proof is not correct then?  Also do you mean $f(x) = x - a + 1$?

Comment: Yes, $\psi$. Well, your assertion that $\psi$ must be an isomorphism is false. You don’t *prove* that, you just assert it, and it is patently the case that this is not always true, as the example I just gave demonstrates.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin but I proved it, I showed that $(f)$ is maximal in $R$.  $R/(f)$ is then a field.  And $R/(f) \to \Bbb{Z}/(f(a))$ is surjective.

Comment: The issue is that the kernel of the map $R\to \mathbb{Z}/(f(a))$ under evaluation at $a$ *contains* $(f(x))$, but it need not be *equal* to $(f(x))$. Your map $\psi$ need not be one-to-one. So your map can be the zero map. You did not prove that $\psi$ is an isomorphism, because you did not prove it is one-to-one.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I'm not taking that map, I didn't take the kernel of $R \to \Bbb{Z}/(f(a))$, I showed that $R/(f) \to \Bbb{Z}/(f(a))$ is a well-defined ring hom.

Comment: Also, for trivial cases like $f(a) = 1$ couldn't we some how rule some out and preserve the argument?

Comment: Yes, but it can be the zero map. Your map is a map given by evaluation at $a$. The kernel of this map contains both $f(x)$ and $x-a$.  So when $f(x)$ is irreducible, and not equal to $x-a$, the kernel is the whole thing and your map is the zero map. It doesn’t matter that the domain is a field: you are mapping everything to $0$, unless $f(x)=x-a$.

Comment: Note also that “generates a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$” does not necessarily imply “generates a maximal ideal in $R$”. You need to prove that. For instance, $(x)$ is maximal in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, but its retraction to $\mathbb{Z}$ is not maximal in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I think you're assuming in some way that my map is a composition of $\pi : \Bbb{Z} \to \Bbb{Z}/(f(a))$ and $\text{ev}_a : R \to \Bbb{Z}$.  It's not though - it's actually harder to prove that *that* composition has the desired properties.  Didn't I prove  surjectivity?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I proved it like so:  if $f = ab$ in $R$, where neither $a, b$ is a unit, then $f = ab$ in $\Bbb{Q}[X]$, so if $f$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{Q}[X]$, then $f$ can't be reducible in $R$.  Therefore it's irreducible.  Please show me exactly where in my proof that I made a mistake.  That will bypass a lot of arguing :)

Comment: First: you map is given by evaluation at $a$. You *define it* as being given by evaluation at $a$. Is it, or is it not the case that $(x-a)+(f(x))$ is in the kernel of $\psi$? Of course it is: your formula says $\psi((x-a)+(f(x)) = (a-a)+f(a) = 0 +f(a)  = 0_{\mathbb{Z}/(f(a))}$. Your assertion that $\psi$ is an isomorphism fails unless $x-a\in (f(x))$. I’m also not sure that $(f(x))$ is maximal; it may be maximal among principal ideals, but why is $R$ a PID? I don’t think it is. I don’t think you have a warrant for asserting $R/(f)$ is a field, or $\psi$ an isomorphism.

Comment: An ideal generated by an irreducible is only guaranteed to be maximal in a PID. In an arbitrary domain, it is only guaranteed to be maximal *among principal ideals*, but the ideal need not be maximal. E.g., $2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, but $(2)$ is not a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I have shown that $\psi$ is always surjective.  Therefore your comment about not being a PID is probably what went wrong.

Comment: Well, and that the target need not be a field, so you could be having the zero map into the zero ring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems: your assertion that $R/(f)$ is a field is unwarranted. Your assertion that $\psi$ is one-to-one is unwarranted.

1. You try to deduce that $R/(f)$ is a field from the conclusion that $f$ is irreducible in the case at hand ($f$ monic and irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$). But the implication
   $$f\text{ is irreducible}\implies (f)\text{ is maximal}$$
   holds in a PID, but not in an arbitrary domain. You can only conclude that $(f)$ is maximal *among principal ideals*. For instance, $2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, but $(2)$ is not maximal: it is properly contained in $(2,x)$. Likewise, here $(f)$ is generated by an irreducible, but unless $R$ is a PID (and I’m pretty sure it is not), then you have no warrant to assert that $R/(f)$ is a field.
2. Your assertion that $\psi$ is an isomorphism of fields assumes that (1) the target is a field; and (2) $\psi$ is one to one. It’s possible that the target is trivial (if $f(a)=\pm 1$); in which case you don’t get an isomorphism of fields. And, more relevant, $\psi$ need not be one-to-one: in general, its kernel will contains $(x-a)+(f(x))$. If we are assuming that $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and monic, then $x-a\in(f(x))$ only if $x-a=f(x)$, which will not be the case in most instances. So $\psi$ usually has non-trivial kernel, which is okay since $(f)$ is only maximal among *principal* ideals, but not necessarily all ideals of $R$.

Comment: I think you misread when you said $x-a \in (f(x))$.  $(f(x))$ is not the kernel of $\psi$.  What are your thoughts here?

Comment: Thank you for the detailed responses.  I learned some stuff.  I didn't know that about PID's and maximality.  So $(f)$ is maximal among principals.  Got it! :D

Comment: @StudySmarterNotHarder: a bit hand-wavey: basically, you have a composite map $R\to R/(f)\to \mathbb{Z}/(f(a))$ given by $g(x)\to g(x)+(f(x))\to g(a)+(f(a))$. The map $\psi$ would be an isomorphism only if the kernel of this composite map is $(f(x))$.

Comment: Arturo, well played, my friend.  :)  You tought me a real lesson.  I'm just another victim of the Shinzel Hypothesis & prime numbers.